# axios.post works in postman but fails in frontend react

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

Searchinfor last 2 days.Nothing works.Something really confusing is going on.I am new to MERN. Axios.get method works properly on browser,but when i try to use axios.post the Request failed with status code 500. post method works fine in postman.in package.json proxy is
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/api/"

this is the code

```
    import axios from "axios";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./register.css";

const Register = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      try{
          const res = await axios.post("/auth/register",{
          username,
          email,
          password
      });
      console.log(res);
      }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
      }  
    
  }


  return (
    <div className="register">
      <span className="registerTitle">Register</span>
      <form className="registerForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
        <label>Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="registerInput"
          placeholder="Username"
         onChange={(e)=>setUsername(e.target.value)}
        />

        <label>Email</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          className="registerInput"
          placeholder="Email"
          onChange={(e)=>setEmail(e.target.value)}
         
        />

        <label>Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          className="registerInput"
          placeholder="password"
          onChange={(e)=>setPassword(e.target.value)}
          
        />
        <button className="registerButton" type="submit">
          Register
        </button>
      </form>
      <button className="registerLoginButton">
        <Link to="/login" className="link">
          Login
        </Link>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

backend code is

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");


//register
router.post("/register",async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const hassedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,salt);
        const newUser = new User({
            username: req.body.username,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hassedPass,

        });
        const user = await newUser.save();
        res.status(200).json(user);

    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }

})
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the backend router to ```/auth/register```?

Comment: yes sir, in index.js this is the code app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP status code 500 is a generic error response. It means that the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Means something is wrong with the server code or server.

Try changing the router to `/auth/register` URL in `router.post()`